# How to add element into the palette view - IBM Mobile First 6.3

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, palette

I am developing mobile apps using IBM Mobile First 6.3 with JQM. I need a clarification that, is there any option for adding element into the palette view and also can we create some variable with default value and keep it any view, so that when we needed we just drag and drop into the function so it will be available.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880024/how-to-add-customize-fields-on-palette-in-eclipse) found when surfing, but no answer is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Palette view is part of Eclipse, so you should refer to Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fuserinterface%2Fpalette.html

MobileFirst Platform populates the palette view based on the used jQuery Mobile .zip that you provided; there is no support to add elements to it. You might be able to based on the Eclipse documentation but this is not a supported path by IBM.